# Android: TileMode transparent instead of CLAMP or REPEAT

Tags: android, drawing

I'm using a shader for drawing images onto a canvas:

```
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
```

The thing is: I don't want the image to repeat or clamp, i just want that those areas are skipped, or you could say "overpainted with transparent color". So only draw those pixels which are defined, no new pixel information should be created.

Anyone knows how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a workaround would be to use `TileMode.CLAMP` with a transparent edge color in the bitmap.